# Create JS Date class from format Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: javascript

I am newbie in JS programming language and i got stuck in a little problem. I have an AjaxRequest with receive variable in JSON format. One of those parameters are a date with the following format Y-m-d H:i:s (eg 2015-02-07 11:52:26), and i want to compare with current date. The issue is that i cannot convert into Date object, and, also i cannot make it on the controller side to have the requested formt Y-m-dTH:i:s. I am wondering if i could do anything to compare those date.

Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand the question, why cant you do this `new Date('2015-02-07 11:52:26')`

Comment: Because firebug returns invalid date Date {Invalid Date}

Comment: You need to replace the dashes `-` with forward slashes `/` in order to makes this a valid date that can be parsed by `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```js
var date = "2015-02-07 11:52:26"; //in your code the request data returned as JSON string

dateEdit = date.replace(/-/g, "/");
dateEdit = new Date(dateEdit);
document.write("Using /: " + dateEdit.toString());

dateEdit = date.replace(/\s/g, "T");
dateEdit = new Date(dateEdit);
document.write("<br /><br />Using T: " + dateEdit.toString());
```

Or replace the space between the date and the time with a capital `T` to render this as a valid string: